# Wexflow .net core version can't open dashboard after installation - 404

Tags: .net-core, workflow

I've downloaded Wexflow version .net core on Windows:

```
https://github.com/aelassas/Wexflow/wiki/Installation
```

I extracted folder, clicked install, folder Wexflow-dotnet-core and WexflowTesting has been created. Then I clicked run.bat and server started. But I can only display swagger-ui page when I type localhost:8000 in my browser. I get page: `http://localhost:8000/swagger-ui/index.html`
And thats all. How to run dashboard.html ? When I type this url in browser I get 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the dashboard, go to "Backend" folder from the zip you downloaded from GitHub and double-click on the file "index.html". Or you can host the backend in a web server by copy/pasting the content of the "Backend" folder into the web server.